# Problems with Java's Paint method, ridiculous refresh velocity

Tags: java, swing, awt, paint, repaint

I'm developing a very simple version of R-Type  as work for the university, but despite it works, the craft velocity is a lot of slow, so the movement is ugly and clumsy.
I use the method repaint for refresh the screen, there are others methods or ways best than it?

[Video of Movement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9KL7N35BS4&feature=youtu.be)

**Paint method at main Panel**

```
@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.drawImage(fondo, 0, 0,1200,600,this);
        pj.paint(g2);
        g2D=g2;

    }
```

**PJ's paint method**

```
public void paint(Graphics2D g) {

    g.drawImage(imagen,x,y,this);
}
```

**PJ's move method**

```
public void move (KeyEvent e)  {
    int dx = 0; int dy = 0;
    int code = e.getKeyCode();

    switch (code) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_Q: dy-=1; break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_A: dy+=1; break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_P: dx+=1; break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_O: dx-=1; break;
    }

    int x = (getX()<maxX&&getX()!=0) ? getX()+dx : getX();
    int y = (getY()<maxY&&getY()!=0) ? getY()+dy : getY();

    if (getY()>=maxY||getY()==0) {
        if (dy==+1) y=y+1;
    }

    setPosicion(x, y); 

}
```

Comment: try bench-marking each step in the paint method at main Panel to see what part is the slowest and come back with the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The image `fondo` should already be scaled to 1200x600.
- I am not sure, but is `super.paint(g)` needed? You might also use `paintComponent`.

The event handling (you seem to be moving by 1 pixel on key down), must be done correctly. I would have set the direction and speed (1px), and leave it to a swing timer to do the continuous moving.

Repainting best is done resilient/flexible: `repaint(20L)` (50 frames per second);
events like key-down maybe with `EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { ... });`.

Especially you might use repaint with the changed area.

Comment: PaintComponet would be preferred, but yes, super.paint is required. Better use a Swing Timer the a delayed repaint -IMHO

Answer (score 2):

You can find a great example of a similar program [here](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/spaceinvaders/). The example demonstrates creating a new thread and having that thread sleep every iteration through the main loop.

[Here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr96/cs333/java/tutorial/ui/drawing/movingImage.html) is another question about loading images for games in Java.

It looks like swing itself is pretty crummy for using images in games. You may want to consider using a more suitable library.

Comment: Swing's okay for most 2D style games, the only think to worry about is that Swing uses a passive rendering process, meaning that while you can request a repaint, you can't guarantee when that repaint will occur

Comment: Hi there Mad! :D  
Yeah, I haven't really done much game development in Java, I was just going off the comments and whatnot in the other thread. They seemed to indicate that while Swing may not be particularly bad at rendering and whatnot, it just isn't very good with images. If I recall correctly, I think you can call revalidate() before repaint() to ensure repaint occurs...

Answer (score 2):

Below is simple example using a background as simple game loop.  It updates the state of the game objects and calculates the required delay in order to maintain the required fps.

The game object (`Ship`) has the ability to accelerate/decelerate over a short period of time

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class AnimationTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AnimationTest();
    }

    public AnimationTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new GamePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class GamePane extends JPanel {

        private Ship ship;

        public GamePane() {

            ship = new Ship();
            Thread thread = new Thread(new MainLoop(this));
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            thread.start();

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            // Key controls...
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false), "upPressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false), "downPressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true), "upReleased");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), "downReleased");

            am.put("upPressed", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // Change the direction...
                    ship.setDirection(-1);
                    // Accelerate by 1 per frame
                    ship.setVelocity(1);
                }

            });
            am.put("downPressed", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // Change direction
                    ship.setDirection(1);
                    // Accelerate by 1 per frame
                    ship.setVelocity(1);
                }

            });
            am.put("upReleased", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // Deccelerate by 1 per frame
                    ship.setVelocity(-1);
                }

            });
            am.put("downReleased", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // Deccelerate by 1 per frame
                    ship.setVelocity(-1);
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        public void updateState() {
            // Update the state of the game objects.
            // This would typically be better done in 
            // some kind of model
            ship.update(getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            // Paint the game state...
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            ship.paint(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class MainLoop implements Runnable {

        private GamePane pane;
        private int fps = 25;

        public MainLoop(GamePane pane) {
            this.pane = pane;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Wait until the screen is ready
            while (pane.getHeight() <= 0) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(125);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
            // Main loop
            while (true) {
                // Start time loop
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                // Update the game state
                pane.updateState();
                // Calculate the amount of time it took to update
                long elasped = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                // Calculate the number of milliseconds we need to sleep
                long sleep = Math.round((1000f / fps) - elasped);
                pane.repaint();
                if (sleep > 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(sleep);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static class Ship {

        public static int MAX_SPEED = 8;
        private int direction = 0;
        private int velocity = 0;
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int speed = 0;
        private Path2D shape;
        private boolean initState;

        public Ship() {
            shape = new Path2D.Float();
            shape.moveTo(0, 0);
            shape.lineTo(5, 5);
            shape.lineTo(0, 10);
            shape.lineTo(0, 0);
            shape.closePath();
            initState = true;
        }

        public void setDirection(int direction) {
            this.direction = direction;
        }

        public void setVelocity(int velocity) {
            this.velocity = velocity;
        }

        public void update(int width, int height) {
            if (initState) {
                y = (height - 10) / 2;
                initState = false;
            } else {
                // Add the velocity to the speed
                speed += velocity;
                // Don't over accelerate
                if (speed > MAX_SPEED) {
                    speed = MAX_SPEED;
                } else if (speed < 0) {
                    speed = 0;
                }
                // Adjust out position if we're moving
                if (speed > 0) {
                    y += (direction * speed);
                }

                // Bounds check...
                if (y - 5 < 0) {
                    y = 5;
                } else if (y + 5 > height) {
                    y = height - 5;
                }
            }
        }

        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
            int yPos = y - 5;
            g2d.translate(10, yPos);
            g2d.fill(shape);
            g2d.translate(-10, -yPos);
        }

    }

}
```