# java - Can Keybinders Implement the keyPressed and keyReleased methods?

Tags: java, key-bindings

I'm looked through the tutorials on how to use key bindings, and I have used them before, but now the situation is different. I have a piano roll, the keys of which correspond to keyboard keys. I need to use the keyPressed and keyReleased  methods to the program knows when to stop and start the piano note.

EDIT:

Here's the working code after getting the answer:

In the JLayeredPane constructor:

```
     InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap am = getActionMap();
        mapKeyboard(im, am);
```

and the method and classes for respective keyPressed/keyReleased actions:

```
    public void mapKeyboard(InputMap im, ActionMap am)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j<10; j++)
        {
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyCodes[count], 0, false), "KeyDown" + count + "");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyCodes[count], 0, true), "KeyUp" + count + "");

            am.put("KeyDown" + count + "", new WhiteKeyDown(count, j));
            am.put("KeyUp" + count + "", new WhiteKeyUp(count, j));
            count++;
        }

        for(int j = 0; j<7; j++)
        {
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyCodes[count], 0, false), "KeyDown" + count + "");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyCodes[count], 0, true), "KeyUp" + count + "");

            am.put("KeyDown" + count + "", new BlackKeyDown(count, j));
            am.put("KeyUp" + count + "", new BlackKeyUp(count, j));
            count++;
        }

        for(int j = 10; j<17; j++)
        {
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyCodes[count], 0, false), "KeyDown" + count + "");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyCodes[count], 0, true), "KeyUp" + count + "");

            am.put("KeyDown" + count + "", new WhiteKeyDown(count, j));
            am.put("KeyUp" + count + "", new WhiteKeyUp(count, j));
            count++;
        }

        for(int j = 7; j<12; j++)
        {
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyCodes[count], 0, false), "KeyDown" + count + "");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyCodes[count], 0, true), "KeyUp" + count + "");

            am.put("KeyDown" + count + "", new BlackKeyDown(count, j));
            am.put("KeyUp" + count + "", new BlackKeyUp(count, j));
            count++;
        }

    }


    class WhiteKeyDown extends AbstractAction
    {
        int index;

        public WhiteKeyDown(int i, int j)
        {
            super("KeyDown" + i + "");
            index = j;
            putValue(Action.NAME, "KeyDown" + i + "");
            putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, "KeyDown" + i + "");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ke) {
            if(isWhiteDown[index] == false)
            {
                channel.noteOn (((WhiteKey) WhiteKeys[index]).getNote (), 127);
                isWhiteDown[index] = true;
                WhiteKeys[index].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                Key key = (Key) WhiteKeys[index];
                CreateOnEvent(key);
            }
        }
    }

    class WhiteKeyUp extends AbstractAction
    {
        int index;

        public WhiteKeyUp(int i, int j)
        {
            super("KeyUp" + i + "");
            index  = j;
            putValue(Action.NAME, "KeyUp" + i + "");
            putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, "KeyUp" + i + "");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ke) {
            if(isWhiteDown[index] == true)
            {
                channel.noteOff (((WhiteKey) WhiteKeys[index]).getNote (), 127);
                isWhiteDown[index] = false;
                WhiteKeys[index].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                Key key = (Key) WhiteKeys[index];
                CreateOffEvent(key);
            }
        }
    }

    class BlackKeyDown extends AbstractAction
    {
        int index;

        public BlackKeyDown(int i, int j)
        {
            super("KeyDown" + i + "");
            index = j;
            putValue(Action.NAME, "KeyDown" + i + "");
            putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, "KeyDown" + i + "");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ke) {
            if(isBlackDown[index] == false)
            {
                channel.noteOn (((BlackKey) BlackKeys[index]).getNote (), 127);
                isBlackDown[index] = true;
                BlackKeys[index].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                Key key = (Key) BlackKeys[index];
                CreateOnEvent(key);
            }
        }
    }

    class BlackKeyUp extends AbstractAction
    {
        int index;

        public BlackKeyUp(int i, int j)
        {
            super("KeyUp" + i + "");
            index = j;
            putValue(Action.NAME, "KeyUp" + i + "");
            putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, "KeyUp" + i + "");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ke) {
            if(isBlackDown[index] == true)
            {
                channel.noteOff (((BlackKey) BlackKeys[index]).getNote (), 127);
                isBlackDown[index] = false;
                BlackKeys[index].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                Key key = (Key) BlackKeys[index];
                CreateOffEvent(key);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes you can have a different Action for keyPressed and keyReleased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes...

See [`KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(int, int, boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke%28int,%20int,%20boolean%29)

And a simple [exmple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897947/problems-with-javas-paint-method-ridiculous-refresh-velocity/15900205#15900205)

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out right before I saw you post. Nonetheless, much appreciated!

Here's the resultant code:

        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, 0, false), "ZKeyDown");
  im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, 0, true), "ZKeyUp");
  
  
     piano.getActionMap().put("ZKeyDown", new ZKeyDown("ZKeyDown"));
     piano.getActionMap().put("ZKeyUp", new ZKeyUp("ZKeyUp"));

(And the Abstract Classes too of course)

Comment: @AFinch, update your question with the code. We can't read code posted in a comment.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. I will have implemented this shortly and I'll post that, because it's way, way better than this.