# Moving player in semi cardinal directions using Java Canvas

Tags: java, canvas

I am trying to create a game so that the player can move in all directions (N,NW,W,SW,S,SE,E,NE) although when I capture the key strokes it will move me once in one of the diagonal directions then, but if I hold them down it switches to one of the cardinal directions(N,W,S,E).

Main Class Key Listener

```
    private class MultiKeyPressListener extends KeyAdapter {

    private final Set<Character> pressed = new HashSet<Character>();

    @Override
    public synchronized void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {       
        pressed.add(e.getKeyChar());
        if(pressed.size() > 1){

            System.out.println(pressed);
            //LEFT UP PRESSED
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP
                    || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                player.direction = "NW";
            }
            //UP RIGHT PRESSED
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT
                    || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                player.direction = "NE";

            }
            //RIGHT DOWN PRESSED
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN
                    || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                player.direction = "SE";
            }
        }else{
            //DOWN LEFT PRESSED
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN
                    || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                player.direction = "SW";
            }
            //LEFT PRESSED
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                player.direction = "W";
            }
            //DOWN PRESSED
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                player.direction = "S";
            }
            //RIGHT PRESSED
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                player.direction = "E";
            }
            //UP PRESSED
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                player.direction = "N";
            }
        }
        player.move();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        pressed.remove(e.getKeyChar());
    }
}
```

Player Class

```
        public void move(){
    if(direction.equals("N")){
        y-= moveRate;
    }else if(direction.equals("NW")){
        y-= moveRate;
        x-= moveRate;
    }else if(direction.equals("W")){
        x-= moveRate;
    }else if(direction.equals("SW")){
        x-= moveRate;
        y+= moveRate;
    }else if(direction.equals("S")){
        y+= moveRate;
    }else if(direction.equals("SE")){
        y+= moveRate;
        x+= moveRate;
    }else if(direction.equals("E")){
        x+= moveRate;
    }else if(direction.equals("NE")){
        x+= moveRate;
        y-= moveRate;
    }
    //System.out.println("Moving " + direction);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to receive two events simultaneously, that is you won't receive `KeyEvent.VK_LEFT` AND `KeyEvent.VK_UP`, you'll only receive one after the other.

What you should try and do, is each time a key is pressed, raise a flag or add it to some kind of `List`, when a key is released, reset the flag or remove it from the `List`.

When you want to determine which direction the character is moving, you would inspect each of these flags and make your decision about the movement...

I would also recommend the use of [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener`, as it does not suffer from the same focus related issues...

For example

- [Problems with Java's Paint method, ridiculous refresh velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897947/problems-with-javas-paint-method-ridiculous-refresh-velocity/15900205#15900205) (this is quite interesting, as it I'll accelerate the object while the key is pressed (to a maximum speed) and will decelerate the object after you release it, but that's just me)
- [How can i make multiple Key Bindings work at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672834/how-can-i-make-multiple-key-bindings-work-at-the-same-time/20672914#20672914)
- [Detecting multiple keypresses in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528953/detecting-multiple-keypresses-in-java/13537419#13537419)

Comment: Could you possibly give me some sample code, or links? Thanks!